# bash: trap reaction - different timing

Tags: bash, shell-script

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

```
[curious ~]# cat ./trap-term
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo TRAP' TERM
sleep 30
[curious ~]# ./trap-term & sleep 3; kill -TERM %1
[1] 3141
   <... pause - 3s>
[curious ~]# Terminated
TRAP
[1]+  Exit 143                ./trap-term
```

Reaction is immediate (3s)?!

```
[curious ~]# cat ./tt
#!/bin/bash
./trap-term & sleep 3; kill -TERM %1
[curious ~]# ./tt <... pause - 3s>
[curious ~]# <... pause - 30s> TRAP
```

Reaction agrees with bash doc:

> If Bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for
> which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the
> command completes.

The question is why the first variant is so much faster than other??

Update:

Test in another distro:

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64);
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu):
the same first result with "Terminated" and "TRAP" after 3s

@zevzek "there are no jobs in shell scripts"??!

```
curious ~$ cat ./ttj 
#!/bin/bash 
./trap-term & sleep 3; jobs; kill -TERM %1 
curious ~$ ./ttj 
[1]+  Running                 ./trap-term & 
curious ~$ TRAP
```

Comment: Are you sure the job is always `%1`? It's safer to use `$!`.

Comment: I can't really reproduce your first example.  The `TRAP` output always comes after 30 seconds, not 3. What shell are you using? The `bash` shell does not usually output "Exit 143".  Mine says "Done" there instead. I also can't reproduce your second example. The script always exits after 3 seconds and the `TRAP` output comes after 30.  You will have to say more about the context of your issue.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu); " TRAP output comes after 30" - like I say

Comment: @curious It's unclear what the timing are in your example. In the first example, you say "pause 3s", then you show a prompt (with the text `Terminated`, which I never see when I test), then `TRAP`. So it's clear when the prompt shows up, but not when `TRAP` is outputted after that.  In the second example, you say "pause 30s" before the prompt with the text `TRAP`. So it appears that the prompt and the text appears at the same time.  Also, "immediate" is not the same as "after 3 seconds", which fuels the confusion.

Comment: first:  TRAP output comes after 3; second:  TRAP output comes after 30

Comment: Linux curious 4.14.35-1902.4.8.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Sun Aug 4 22:25:18 GMT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Test in another distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64); GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu); the same first result with "Terminated" and "TRAP" after 3s

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Comment: @zevzek "`kill -TERM %1` is killing" - no, it is only sending the TERM signal for `trap ... TERM`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the answer by myself.

Second case: noninteractive shell - job control is disabled - needs `set -m`.

```
[curious ~]# cat ./tta
#!/bin/bash
set -m; ./trap-term & sleep 3; kill -TERM %1
[curious ~]# ./tta 
<... pause - 3s>
Terminated
TRAP
[curious ~]#
```